# SearchView implementation in Volley Library data

Tags: android, android-volley, searchview

I am getting data and populate it in ListView using Volley Library.It is working fine.But now I need to implement search filter.I am messed up of implement it.Please help me.

Here, Where I need to send my **SEARCH QUERY** into server.

Your answer is more appreciated.

Here is my code to get data from server using Volley Library:

```
private void getData() {
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            parseData(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

private void parseData(JSONArray array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Restaurant_Beam superHero = new Restaurant_Beam();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            superHero.setStr_categoryName(json.getString(Config.CATEGORY_NAME));
            superHero.setStr_productName(json.getString(Config.PRODUCT_NAME));
            superHero.setStrPrice(json.getInt(String.valueOf(Config.PRICE)));
            superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            superHero.setTAB_NAME(json.getString(Config.TAB_NAME));
            superHero.setLikeCount(json.getInt(Config.LIKE_COUNT));
            superHero.setCommentCount(json.getInt(Config.COMMENT_COUNT));
            superHero.setProduct_id(json.getString(Config.PRODUCT_ID));
            String productId = json.getString(Config.LIKE_COUNT);

            product_Id.add(productId);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (superHero.getTAB_NAME().contains(currentTab)) {

            listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
            adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't make an instance of adapter in every adding item. you must before loop make an instance adapter and set it to your recycler. then after every adding item to your data, notifyDatasetChenaged your adapter. Do everything well.
do your parseData like below:

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
   //TODO make an instance listSuperHeroes
    adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, context);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);  
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Restaurant_Beam superHero = new Restaurant_Beam();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                superHero.setStr_categoryName(json.getString(Config.CATEGORY_NAME));
                superHero.setStr_productName(json.getString(Config.PRODUCT_NAME));
                superHero.setStrPrice(json.getInt(String.valueOf(Config.PRICE)));
                superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                superHero.setTAB_NAME(json.getString(Config.TAB_NAME));
                superHero.setLikeCount(json.getInt(Config.LIKE_COUNT));
                superHero.setCommentCount(json.getInt(Config.COMMENT_COUNT));
                superHero.setProduct_id(json.getString(Config.PRODUCT_ID));
                String productId = json.getString(Config.LIKE_COUNT);

                product_Id.add(productId);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (superHero.getTAB_NAME().contains(currentTab)) {
                listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
                adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please explain me.I dont understand what you are trying to say. @Haniyeh Khaksar

Comment: @ParamaSudha you can't make an instance of adapter in every adding item. you must before loop make an instance adapter and set it to your recycler. then after every adding item to your data, notifyDatasetChenaged your adapter.

Comment: I have some data in server...I need to get some specific data by searching.For that I need to POST the SEARCH_STRING into there to get values. Here where I need to POST the String to Server.

Comment: I think it is better you define your data and adapter global (as field in start of your class). then before you get data from server, you make an instance from your list of data and adapter, and set your adapter to your recycler view. because you have no data, so your recycler view don't show any thing. after send your request to server. when get data, you can clear old data from list and add new data to list and notifyDatasetchanged for adapter.